# Trying to customize notifications in macOS with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, notifications, macos-catalina

I am using macOS 10.5.6 and I am trying to display a custom notification.  I am using `UNNotificationAction` to set up a drop down menu for the notification and `UNNotificationCategory` to save it. I can get the notification correctly. The title and body are displayed but the popup menu for the notification is displayed under a button labeled "Actions".

What I would like to happen is have the label "Actions" changed to a two button format the way that the Reminders app does. I have spent a couple of days searching this web site and several others trying to find the answer but all I have found is the method I am currently using to set up the notification with out the button format that I would like to display.  I know that it can be done I just do not know which key words to use to get the answer I would appreciate any help I can get.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAZ19.png)

Comment: Welcome Jim. Please, take the SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Actionable notifications are described in the [Declaring Your Actionable Notification Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types) article. It works as expected, two buttons when you follow it. If it doesn't work for you, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question with your code.

Comment: I cannot add an image of the notification I am getting. Does "Declaring Your Actionable Notification Types" work for mac OS.  The information in the website is basically what I am doing in mac OS only for iOS.

Answer (score 4):

## Sample notifications

A notification with an attachment:

[image]

A notification with an attachment, mouse is hovering over to make the action buttons visible (they're visible right away if there's no attachment).

[image]

## Sample project

### Delegate

`AppDelegate` is going to handle notifications in the following sample project. We have to make it conform to the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol.

```swift
import UserNotifications

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    ...
}
```

We have to set the `UNUserNotificationCenter.delegate` to our `AppDelegate` in order to receive notifications. It must be done in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method.

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    setupNotificationCategories() // See below
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    // Other stuff
}
```

Authorization, capabilities, ... omitted for simplicity.

### Constants

An example how to avoid hardcoded constant.

```swift
enum Note {
    enum Action: String {
        case acceptInvitation = "ACCEPT_INVITATION"
        case declineInvitation = "DECLINE_INVITATION"

        var title: String {
            switch self {
            case .acceptInvitation:
                return "Accept"
            case .declineInvitation:
                return "Decline"
            }
        }
    }

    enum Category: String, CaseIterable {
        case meetingInvitation = "MEETING_INVITATION"

        var availableActions: [Action] {
            switch self {
            case .meetingInvitation:
                return [.acceptInvitation, .declineInvitation]
            }
        }
    }

    enum UserInfo: String {
        case meetingId = "MEETING_ID"
        case userId = "USER_ID"
    }
}
```

### Setup categories

Make the notification center aware of our custom categories and actions. Call this function in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

```swift
func setupNotificationCategories() {
    let categories: [UNNotificationCategory] = Note.Category.allCases
        .map {
            let actions = $0.availableActions
                .map { UNNotificationAction(identifier: $0.rawValue, title: $0.title, options: [.foreground]) }

            return UNNotificationCategory(identifier: $0.rawValue,
                                          actions: actions,
                                          intentIdentifiers: [],
                                          hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder: "",
                                          options: .customDismissAction)
    }

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories(Set(categories))
}
```

### Create a notification content

Sample notification content with an attachment. If we fail to create an
attachment we will continue without it.

```swift
func sampleNotificationContent() -> UNNotificationContent {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Hey Jim! Weekly Staff Meeting"
    content.body = "Every Tuesday at 2pm"
    content.userInfo = [
        Note.UserInfo.meetingId.rawValue: "123",
        Note.UserInfo.userId.rawValue: "456"
    ]
    content.categoryIdentifier = Note.Category.meetingInvitation.rawValue

    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationattachment/1649987-init
    //
    // The URL of the file you want to attach to the notification. The URL must be a file
    // URL and the file must be readable by the current process. This parameter must not be nil.
    //
    // IOW We can't use image from the assets catalog. You have to add an image to your project
    // as a resource outside of assets catalog.

    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "jim@2x", withExtension: "png"),
        let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: url, options: nil) {

        content.attachments = [attachment]
    }

    return content
}
```

**Important**: you can't use an image from the assets catalog, because you need an URL pointing to a file readable by the current process.

[image]

### Trigger helper

Helper to create a trigger which will fire a notification in `seconds` seconds.

```swift
func triggerIn(seconds: Int) -> UNNotificationTrigger {
    let currentSecond = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date())

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current
    dateComponents.second = (currentSecond + seconds) % 60

    return UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
}
```

### Notification request

```swift
let content = sampleNotificationContent()
let trigger = triggerIn(seconds: 5)

let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to add a notification request: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

### Handle notifications

Following functions are implemented in the sample project `AppDelegate`.

#### Background

This is called when your application is in the background (or even if your application is running, see Foreground below).

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
    @escaping () -> Void) {

    guard let action = Note.Action(rawValue: response.actionIdentifier) else {
        print("Unknown response action: \(response.actionIdentifier)")
        completionHandler()
        return
    }

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    guard let meetingId = userInfo[Note.UserInfo.meetingId.rawValue] as? String,
        let userId = userInfo[Note.UserInfo.userId.rawValue] as? String else {
            print("Missing or malformed user info: \(userInfo)")
            completionHandler()
            return
    }

    print("Notification response: \(action) meetingId: \(meetingId) userId: \(userId)")

    completionHandler()
}
```

#### Foreground

This is called when the application is in the foreground. You can handle the notification silently or you can just show it (this is what the code below does).

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
    @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

## iOS customization

There's another way how to [customize the appearance of notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications), but this is not available on the macOS. You have to use attachments.

[image]

Comment: This looks good! It does not appear to have a drop down menu though. Have I missed something?  Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: Just added image of the notification I get. This may help better in describing what is happening.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, this, I don't think it's possible via public API.

Comment: Hi @zrzka  and thanks for the elaborate answer. Questions: For MacOS - how do you determine WHERE on the notification dialog your "Attachment" image will appear? and HOW you get to have 2 buttons (I only get a popup menu with my actions). Second: Are you sure " customize the appearance of notifications, but this is not available on the macOS." ??? Apple doesn't say it explicitly, an I KNOW for a fact that they have customized  notifications (drag 100 files to your  Mac via airdrop, and see a beautiful notification with circular progress-bar)